# Debug SQL Server 2012 Stored Procedure in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to debug the SQL Server 2012 stored procedure from VS 2013. I have able to step in to the stored procedure but the problem is how do I see the value inside the temporary table and table type variables in the stored procedure.

Here is the sample procedure for instance

```
DECLARE @Products ProductsTableType
INSERT INTO @Products SELECT * from Products
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not supported as per I know. If possible try using LINQ.